# In Applescript, how do you debug the Menus and Menu Items of GUI scripting?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

I often see all this crazy stuff with Apple scripting, involving telling menus and menu items, and UI elements and all that crazy soft of stuff to do things. I don't mind that it's kind of a crazy way to get things done - as long as it works - but my question is this: **How do you debug that stuff? I mean, how do you know what your options are?**

I have apple script editor and script debugger, but I'm not sure how to use them to see what the options are. I've tried searching with google but I haven't come up with anything.

I do some web development so I'm used to using Firebug to examine the DOM of a web page, I just assume that there should be something easy and similar to help with Applescript.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to script the GUI or how to tell which GUI elements are available in an application. If the former, try starting with [Graphic User Interface (GUI) Scripting](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html).

If you want to find out what the GUI hierarchy is for an application, check out [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/), which will allow you to see the UI elements of an application and provide the information you need to target one of them.

Comment: But it should be noted that GUI scripting is what one does when the application's Dictionary fails to give the functionality needed to complete a task. It also does not completely work with all applications, depending on how they were built, Firefox 3 and now 4 being a good example of this.

Comment: The UI Browser solved the problem for me, thanks!
@pr - Dropbox also runs as a tray item, of the type "NSStatusItems" and from what I understand these are not possible to script to.